# How to pull a specific value from a database, and display it NOT in a table, but as plain text

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

So I have a MySQL database, which I am comfortable being able to access using PHP and mysqli. Here is my question: I wanted to display a certain value in a row as text, not in a table, on the front page of my website. Let's say the row's name is FirstName. I wanted to display FirstName like so:

Hi there, `FirstName`!

I wanted to know how I am able to do that. I think it should be as simple as connecting to the database, requesting data from the specific table, then just using `.display['`FirstName`']`, however I am unsure if that will actually work...

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose Imagine This is you structure of homepage.php file

```
   <html>

        <h1> Hi there,

         <?php 

          //fetch the data inside this body of php and store it in variable called $UserName or anything 

           echo $UserName."<br>";

         ?> //end of Php code

        </h1> //end of h1 tag

    </html>
```

Comment: Ok, I think it makes sense. So you are saying to fetch the data of my database that I need, save it in a variable, then call the variable, correct?

Comment: Exactly. However if you are making something like redirecting user from some page for example when user login then you are going to display this page at that time send a post request with a post variable from previous page and just use that variable to create local variable or just echo it.However this also works fine